# Is there an implemented Id-based key exchange protocol?

Tags: authentication, key-exchange, identity-based-encryption

I need to use some kind of authentication of the client during my key exchange process. 
During my research, in [this](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/46286685_A_Comparison_Study_on_Key_Exchange-Authentication_protocol) article I learned about identity-based key exchange and authentication, and I was very interested in the idea. 
However, when I started to search for some protocols I could not find anything further than the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID-based_cryptography) page and the most recent solution seems to date from 2001. 
Is there anything I am missing? Or am I just searching for the wrong keywords?

Comment: A fairly typical way to do this is with mutually-authenticated TLS, where both sides (client and server) present a certificate that can be verified by the other party.

Comment: @Marc: TLS certificates are only a practical substitute to what the OP is asking.

Comment: HIMMO was proposed as a primitive that did this; however it was broken.  I don't know of another primitive that does this.

Comment: So I should understand that there is no way to do this currently right?